# Different request and response thread in Kotlin coroutines ( spring mvc )

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-mvc, kotlin-coroutines, mdc

1. Spring boot 2.6.1
2. Kotlin 1.6.0

mycode

```
@Controller
class Test{

    @GetMapping(..)
    suspend fun api(): Response {
      System.out.print(Thread.currentthread()) <-- http-nio-port-exec-1
      
      Webclient().post().url().retrieve().bodyToMono()..awaitSingle() // api call
      System.out.print(Thread.currentthread()) <-- reactor-1
      throw Exception() <- example
      
      return Response.builder(suspend fun...)
    }

    @exceptionhadler
    fun..{
       System.out.print(Thread.currentthread()) <-- http-nio-port-exec-2 ?? why!
    }

}
```

It is being developed through coroutine.
Currently, spring boot 2.6 version supports the suspend function, but the thread of request and response are different, so MDC and trace cannot be tracked.
Could you give me some help?

trace track and Mdc Context

Comment: Have you figured out how to propagate servlet context to coroutine context?